# Retrieve data from URL

Tags: javascript

Obligatory disclaimer : I'm inexperienced in JS and know only the very basics. Please expect some stupid questions...

I have a URL that goes like https://example.com/something/another-thing/int:id/
I would like to get the <int:id> into a variable in JS. Most methods I searched online shows how to retrieve it from something like https://example.com/something/another-thing?name=some-value but the URL I get can't be in this format.

Any ideas how to get <int:id>? I'm looking for a plain JS solution if possible.

Comment: The link ends with <int:id> but for some reason <> is not rendering in the link

Comment: You could parse the url, if the id is always at the same position.

Comment: @AbhilashRamachandran, I have included my answer to account for your url with <>. Does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the url link in your script already, you can do something like this:

```
let url = 'https://example.com/something/another-thing/<int:id>/';

let split_url = url.split('/');
let variable_name = split_url[5]
console.log(variable_name)
```

You split the url string by the slash, then retrieve the int:id you want from the array.
Here is the jsfiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/na4086t7/3/

Edit: I noticed you said there is a <> inside the link. I have edited my answer accordingly. The code should still work. If you get something like `"&lt;int:id&gt;"`, you can try this

`let variable_name = split_url[5].replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&gt;/g, ">");`

instead of

```
let variable_name = split_url[5]
```

Comment: Thank you @MatCode! This works. Also the <> comment was to explain why the url didn't have <> while I used <> to represent int:id in other places in that question. In an actual scenario, it's something like  https://example.com/something/another-thing/7/ where 7 is an integer data type and represents the id of something. <int:id> is how you represent it in Django, which I'm more familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = 'https://example.com/something/another-thing/int:id/'; //or url = 'https://example.com/something/another-thing/int:id'
var lastIndex = url.lastIndexOf('/');  //return -1 if / not found
var urlLength = url.length;
if(lastIndex != -1 && lastIndex == urlLength - 1) {
    url = url.substr(0, lastIndex);  //if / is at the end replace
}
var arr = url.split('/');
var lastElem = arr[arr.length - 1];  //get the last elem i.e. int:id
console.log(lastElem.replace('<', '').replace('>', ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need regex, `\w mean match [a-zA-Z0-9_]`

```js
var url = 'https://example.com/something/another-thing/int:id/';
var results = url.match(/\/(\w+):(\w+)/)
console.log(results[1])
console.log(results[2])
```